How to use PowerShell to query stock prices
I don't really have a problem, I'm trying to find a better way to get the current price of a stock using PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest.  This is what I'm doing today:
Function Get-StockQuote($Uri) {
    
    $r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -UseBasicParsing
    
    #rip out the current market value in spectacularly unimpressive style
    $rc = $r.Content
    $trimRc = $rc.Substring( $rc.IndexOf('data-last-price="'), 25)
    $rip = $trimRc.Substring($TrimRc.IndexOf('"') + 1, $TrimRc.Length - $TrimRc.IndexOf('"') - 1)
    $value = $rip.Substring(0, $rip.IndexOf('"'))

    return [double]$value

}

$uri = 'https://www.google.com/finance/quote/MSFT:NASDAQ'
Get-StockQuote $uri

I get what I need but it is unreliable and it's just a sloppy way to do this.  I'm looking for a more efficient solution to what feels like a fairly easy thing to do

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Would benefit to explain why it is unreliable.

A regex might be useful here instead of substring handling. I am not sure why you say that it is "unreliable".
Function Get-StockQuote($Uri) {
    $r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -UseBasicParsing
    if ($r.Content -match 'data-last-price="([0-9\.]*)') {
        $value = [double]$Matches[1]
    } else {
        Write-Error -Message 'Price not found'
        $value = [double]0.0
    }

    return [double]$value
}

$uri = 'https://www.google.com/finance/quote/MSFT:NASDAQ'
Get-StockQuote $uri


Thanks for the response here.  I like this better as it returns a 0 value if not found and the regex is smart, neither of which I thought of.  To answer the question of reliable, the format returned changes over time and some markets present data differently than others.  I did look around and couldn't find a reliable way to query stocks which seems like a trivial thing to do, but I tried yahoo finance, google obviously, others, but found nothing that I would call a correct way to do this.  I guess it's slightly less about coding and more about approach which this may not be the forum for

@MattAltimar, glad you have something that works. I understand now that it is not the code that is unreliable, but the data source. That can be difficult to overcome.
